# How to create a forum inside of a application?

Tags: android

Is it possible to have users leave comments and start conversations inside of a application?
If so what would need to be done on the server side and the application side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this kind of situation, you will generally find the following ideas :

**On the server side :**

- have a page / method that returns the data of the forum *(list of categories, list of topics, content of topics / posts, ... )*
- have another page / method which will receive data from the application *(new posts, new topics, ...)*

**And, on the application side :**

- have forms to allow the user to input data *(new posts, new topics, ...)*
- have a couple of display pages *(to display what's in the forum)*
- of course, each display page will link to either :

  - other display pages -- for example, a list of topics will allow one to enter into the topics, to arrive on the list of posts
  - actions -- for example, on a topic, you'll have a "add answer" button

The server and the client will exchange data, often using HTTP requests *(be it SOAP, XML-RPC, REST, ...)*.

Comment: Okay great! Definitely have my on the right track. Do yo know of any tutorial that shows how to do this on the application side? i know its many that are out there for the server side. Or maybe you could provide an example =)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a tutorial about that -- I've developped from scratch, for fun, an application that does pretty much just that *(for a blogging-platform, and not a forum)*, but it's not open source.

Comment: Hu, not really, sorry. But if you have more specific questions, specific problems you encounter while developping, feel free to ask other questions on SO, chances are someone will help here :-) ; just one first advice : start with something small *(like consultation-only, for example)*, and, only when the small application works fine, add some feature, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, but here are some key components:

1. You would need to have a database on the server that saves your data (by data I mean comments, conversations, users, etc)
2. You would need to have a web service on your server that allows access to all your data.
3. The aforementioned web service would also have to allow you to save data to your server's database, when the user starts a new comments or post on the phone.
4. Finally, you would need to create an Android application and include all the necessary UI elements in order to allow users to log in, make comments, browse posts and settings.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider a free community service to embed the forum/commenting feature in your application. Disqus is a good commenting platform service: http://disqus.com/